# Kafka 10 kafka-consumer-groups.sh vs. Kafka 8 kafka-run-class.sh of ConsumerOffsetChecker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to name my consumers in Kafka 10 the same as I did in Kafka 8, since I have scripts that sniff out and use this info further.

Apparently the default naming of the consumer.id has changed (and it also now shows the client.id separately). I didn't see this mentioned or compared in the docs.

In Kafka 10 terms, what is the equivalent I need to do to have it generate the same '<group>*<host>*...' consumer and/or client id format as in Kafka 8 (instead of the 'consumer-#-<guid>' format seen below)?

Kafka 8:

```
/usr/local/kafka-0.8/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zkconnect localhost:2181 --group optimizer-group --topic optimizer-default-topic

Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
optimizer-group optimizer-default-topic        0   17059718        17059725        7               my-group_myhost.com-1497048808577-1575fa11-0
...
```

Kafka 10:

```
/usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group optimizer-group --describe

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
eddude-error-topic             0          0               0               0          consumer-2-e839517b-a150-498d-9054-31ec7a655936   /10.xxx.xx.xxx                 consumer-2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Default consumer id naming convention in 0.8 is hostname-timestamp-[most significant 8 bits of UUID] although you could set `consumer.id` to override it.

However, default consumer id in 0.10 changes to [client.id]-[UUID] and it seems there is no way to specify it directly. The only way is to set `client.id` to indirectly set the consumer id.

Comment: Thanks, I'll verify that I can set the client.id to make its way to the kafka-consumer-groups.sh output. Something like hostname-tid